# How to exclude 0's in arch4random swift

Tags: swift

Is there a way to exclude just 0's from the arch4random method in Swift? Here's my code:

```
let randomNumber=Int(arc4random_uniform(12))
```

But I do not want 0's in my random number.

Comment: Better use `let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 1...11)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!
If you need `Int`, why don't just add 1 and lower range by 1?

```
let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(11)) + 1
```